# How to do NOT NULL check in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Please find below query.

```
select * from table tab1,
table tab2,
table tab3
where tab1.sid = tab2.sid
and tab2.referencedid = tab3.referencedid
```

My requirement is **tab3's** column value which  **tab3.referencedid** is not then use the and condition and populate the records. Please suggest me a way how to achieve this. Based on NOT NULL condition query results should be obtained

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Comment: Do you need to populate data where **tab3.referencedid=NULL** ?

Comment: So you want to UPDATE a row where the referece is NOT NULL or do you want to INSERT rows where the reference for now is NULL?

Comment: Can you add simple example for us and expected result ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listing both null and not null in mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270895/listing-both-null-and-not-null-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you in this case better to use JOIN instend of using join in Where clause

```
SELECT  * 
FROM   table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.sid = t2.sid
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.referencedid = t3.referencedid
WHERE  // here you can add your criteria if you have
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the IS NOT NULL Condition in MySQL is:

`field IS NOT NULL`